# Unit testing of Jar methods in java

Tags: java, junit, apache-poi, mockito, stub

I'm using Apache POI methods for writing to excel sheets in java. I have to do unit-testing for the methods which I have written. I have used many methods of Apache POI. Should I stub all the methods of the different object classes of Apache POI?

Example: I have created wrapper methods for writing to cell which are using Apache POI methods.

```
protected void writeCell(int rowNum, int colNum, String value, Sheet sheet)
{
    if(value == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum);
    cell.setCellValue();
  }

}
```

Should I mock even the methods like `getRow`of `the Sheet.class` and `createCell` of the Row class?

Comment: you don't have to do unit testing for Apache POI methods, you just need to mock them. Also mock only the methods you have used not all of them

Comment: @KP I'm not writing test-cases for Apache POI. I'm writing for my own methods.

Answer (score 3):

Test for results, not implementation.

I.e. If I write a cell, can I now read that value back from that cell?

Also you showed us a `protected` method, you should only need to test the public interface of your classes. If you can't see results though the public interface, your class is probably doing too much (Single Responsibility Principle).

However, the other considerations are ones of speed and fragility, because Apache POI is reading and writing to actual files, it will be a little harder to write these tests and they will be slower. OK for a few tests, but if the whole suite is reading and writing files then it's going to get slow, and the entire test suite should run in a matter of a few seconds ideally.

So I would create an interface that encapsulates an excel sheet and what you want to do with it, this might be:

```
public interface StringGrid {
    String readCell(int rowNum, int colNum);
    void writeCell(int rowNum, int colNum, String value);
}
```

Now I might do a quick implementation without automated tests, or just a few simple tests around Apache POI, but then the rest of my suite would test against a [**Fake**](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) implementation of the `StringGrid` and I can get on creating lots of *fast* running tests around *my* code.

So these might look like:

The real implementation, used only in its tests and the live program.

```
public final class ApacheSheetStringGrid implements StringGrid {

    private final Sheet theApacheSheet;

    public ApacheSheetStringGrid(Sheet theApacheSheet) {
        this.theApacheSheet = theApacheSheet;
    }

    public String readCell(int rowNum, int colNum){
       ...
    }

    public void writeCell(int rowNum, int colNum, String value) {
      Row row = theApacheSheet.getRow(rowNum);
      Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum);
      cell.setCellValue();
    }
}
```

The Fake (a working, fast, in-memory only implementation of `StringGrid`), for all other testing:

```
public final class FakeStringGrid implements StringGrid {

    private final Map<String, String> contents = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private static String getKey(int rowNum, int colNum) {
       return rowNum + ", " + colNum;
    }

    public String readCell(int rowNum, int colNum){
       return contents.get(getKey(rowNum, colNum));
    }

    public void writeCell(int rowNum, int colNum, String value) {
       contents.put(getKey(rowNum, colNum), value);
    }
}
```

This has extra benefits, you can later swap out the live implementation for another, maybe using one of the other POI approaches or even google sheets implementation and you'll only need to add a few tests and a new implementation and won't need to modify any code (Open Closed Principle).

Comment: This is a really efficient solution. Thanks. Should I make all the methods like writeCell (int rowNum, int colNum, String value ) as public for testing them? Because then I cannot test protected methods.

Comment: Well if you follow this, methods like those become `public` on another class. I *only* write `public` methods and I *only* write them to solve failing tests, in my code `private` and `protected` methods *only* come about through [refactoring](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/12/17/TheCyclesOfTDD.html).

Comment: What do you mean by " to solve failing tests" ? Are you saying you write all methods as public first and then later when you later break the bigger method into smaller methods than you make them as private/protected ?

Comment: I mean TDD, Red/Green/Refactor. 1. Write a failing test, (Red) 2. Write **only** enough code to pass that test (Green). 3. Refactor to tidy up (Refactor). And yes only step 3 would *need* to generate private/protected methods (I don't strictly follow that though, step 2 could generate them but still **only** if they are fixing that failing test from step 1).

Comment: Is it fine to use both fake and mock objects in the junit testing code.Example :   when(computationHelper.someMethod()).thenReturn(stringGrid.writeCell(rowNum,colNum,value));

where computationHelper is mock object and stringGrid is my own implementation and a fake object.

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to see the whole test to judge if it makes sense in this case.

Comment: Can we test protected methods of class using Mockito if my test classes are in the same folder as my orginal class ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I tried the way you said but have modified a little. I have posted my whole test description here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667172/faking-method-parameters-using-mockito-powermockito). Please have a look at it once , if possible.

Comment: I looked. Why are you faking everything? Why does it matter that the interfaces expose sheets and rows and columns? Just because apache does? Write interfaces from the consumer POV, not to best fit some library you're using.

Comment: I'm faking at the Apache POI level, since I cannot fake at the protected method writeToCell. So only 2 possibilities to fake at POI methods level or at writeDetailsForCategory. I will have to decide some boundry where I would return the Sheet like Map structure. By looking at my code, at which level should I return the Map.