# Faking Method parameters using Mockito/PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-poi, mockito, powermockito

```
public class FakeExcelSheet implements Sheet
{
     private final Map<Integer, FakeExcelRow> fakeSheet = new HashMap<Integer, FakeExcelRow>();

     @Override
     public Row createRow(int rowNum)
     {
          Row row = new FakeExcelRow(rowNum, fakeSheet);
          fakeSheet.put(rowNum, (FakeExcelRow)row);
          return row;
     }

     @Override
     public Row getRow(int rowNum)
     {
          if (fakeSheet.get(rowNum) != null)
          {
               return fakeSheet.get(rowNum);
          }
          else
          {
               return createRow(rowNum);
          }

     }

     /**Other unimplemented methods of Apache POI class Sheet**/ 
}

public class FakeExcelRow implements Row
{
    private int rowNum;
    private Map<Integer, FakeExcelRow> sheet;
    private List<Object> cellList = new LinkedList<Object>();

    public FakeExcelRow(int rowNum , Map<Integer,FakeExcelRow> sheet)
    {
          this.rowNum = rowNum;
          this.sheet = sheet;
    }

    @Override
    public Cell createCell(int colNum)
    {
         return new FakeExcelCell(colNum, rowNum, sheet);
    }

    /**Other unimplemented methods of Apache POI class Row**/
}

public class FakeExcelCell implements Cell
{
      private int colNum;
      private int rowNum;
      private Map<Integer, FakeExcelRow> sheet;

      public FakeExcelCell(int colNum, int rowNum, Map<Integer, FakeExcelRow> sheet)
      {
          this.colNum = colNum;
          this.rowNum = rowNum;
          this.sheet = sheet;
      }

      public void setCellValue(String value)
      {
           if(sheet != null)
           {
                FakeExcelRow fakeExcelRow = sheet.get(rowNum);
                List<Object> cellList = fakeExcelRow.getCellList();
                cellList.add(value);
           }
      }

      /**Other unimplemented methods of Apache POI class Cell**/
}
```

I have to test the my class Service which is using class ExcelWriter's protected method writeToCell like this :

```
public class ServiceImpl
{
     ........
     .
     .
     private ExcelWriter excelWriter;
     private Sheet sheet;
     private void handleRequest()
     {

           while("Till there are more rows")
           {
           excelWriter.writeDetailsForCategory(List<String> listOfItems)
           }
     }
 }
```

The ExcelWriter Class is designed like this:

```
public class ExcelWriter()
{
     protected Sheet sheet;
     public void writeDetailsForCategory(List<String> listOfItems)
     {
           for(String item : listOfItems)
           {
                 writeToCell(rowNum, columnNum, value, sheet);
                 columnNum++;
           }
     }
}
```

The writeToCell() method is designed with protected access modifier:

```
protected void writeCell(int rowNum, int colNum, String value, Sheet sheet)
{

    if (value == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
    }

    Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum);
    cell.setCellValue(value);

}
```

I have to unit test the `handleRequest` method of the class `ServiceImpl` which uses ExcelWriter's `writeDetailsForCategory` , which is using protected method `writeToCell`. I have pass the `FakeExcelSheet` in the `writeToCell` method.I will assert on the values of the `Map <Object, FakeExcelRow>` after this. How should I pass in the fakeExcelSheet parameter in `protected`  `writeToCell` method? My constraints are that I can use Mockito or PowerMockito only.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638877/360211), you could replace the specific `ExcelWriter` with a `StringGridWriter`, which writes to a given `StringGrid`. It does not know or care that it is excel.

```
public final class StringGridWriter() {
     private final StringGrid grid;

     public StringGridWriter(StringGrid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
     }

     public void writeDetailsForCategory(List<String> listOfItems) {
           for(String item : listOfItems) {
                 grid.writeToCell(rowNum, columnNum, value);
                 columnNum++;
           }
     }
}
```

Usage in service:

```
public class ServiceImpl {
     ........
     .
     .
     private final StringGridWriter gridWriter;

     public ServiceImpl(StringGridWriter gridWriter) {
         this.gridWriter = gridWriter;
     }

     private void handleRequest() {    
           while("Till there are more rows"){
             gridWriter.writeDetailsForCategory(List<String> listOfItems)
           }
     }
 }
```

And this is how you'd assign to it to use it:

```
Sheet theApacheSheet = ...;

StringGrid grid = new ApacheSheetStringGrid(theApacheSheet);

StringGridWriter writer = new StringGridWriter(grid);

ServiceImpl service = new ServiceImpl(writer);
```

Where `ApacheSheetStringGrid` is as per my other answer. So now, even the `ServiceImpl` has no idea that this is using excel. This injection of dependencies is the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html) in practice.

See how I rapidly get away from the complicated excel interfaces and boil it down to just an abstraction, a subset of functionality, which is only the interface my client wants ([Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html)), which makes it both easy to test, and easy to replace with other implementations. By not abstracting you are tightly coupling your code to the apache excel implementation.